# How to make a custom font, hospeded in an IIS server, work in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, iis, webfonts

how are you? I'm trying to make a barcode font work on IE. I need to host this font in a IIS server.

So far I only managed to this work if the font is local, in the same folder of the HTML file, as this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Libre Barcode 39 Extended Text';
  src: url('barcode.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local('Libre Barcode 39 Extended Text'), 
   local('LibreBarcode39ExtendedText-Regular'),
       url('barcode.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('barcode.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('barcode.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('barcode.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('barcode.svg#LibreBarcode39ExtendedText') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
```

}

But if I change the "barcode.extension" to a http:// address the font itself don't change anymore. I already have gave Full-Control access to the folder where the file is to test but doenst seems to have any difference.

Aren't this: url('http://example/example/barcode.woff') format('woff'), supposed to work?

Comment: It can be the CORS related issue where IE not allowing to access the resources from other domain. Try to go to tools-> Internet options->security-> custom level-> Access data sources across domains and Enable it. http://i.postimg.cc/fR6vyCMZ/144.png

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. I've tried these changes but got no success, unfortunatelly. Have a nice day.

Comment: Did you try to set MIME type in IIS for your web fonts? If not, You can try to set it for testing purpose. It may help to solve this issue. Ref: https://manage.accuwebhosting.com/knowledgebase/2443/How-to-set-MIME-types-for-web-fonts-in-IIS.html and http://codingstill.com/2013/01/set-mime-types-for-web-fonts-in-iis/

Comment: Yes I had. Actually one of erros of the IIS gives is "the MIME types may not have been configured." I've double checked and all possible fonts extensions are in the MIME types.

Comment: Does that error got solved from the IIS? do you mean you got multiple errors from IIS? If yes than it can be the possible reason that your font is not working with IE.

Comment: Ah sorry, the error just appear for woff2 and it disapears after I've added this MIME Map, so all extensions are mapped now. Still the HTML don't show the font if I refeer the http instead of the UNC Path. I think I'll probably speak with the customer and ask him to put the font on all the machines.

Comment: Can you please check whether you are getting any error or warning message in the console of IE? If there is any error message than it can also help to find the cause for the issue.

Comment: Hey man, no erros on IE Console too. I'll install the font in each machine, unfortunatelly. Anyway, thank you for your time!

Comment: You can also try to refer this article may help to solve your issue. Ref: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/6498/how-to-solve-font-icons-missing-issue-when-host-the-sample-in-iis